# Do I still need Microsoft.Bcl.Build in .net 4.5+

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Firstly, I don't actually know what the Microsoft.Bcl.Build for and I tried to understand it but I found it so confused. I am wondering if I still need it or not for .net 4.5+

Answer (score 1):

You don't, but many NuGet packages are not yet updated to reflect that (some Google's for example), so you will still need to use it from time to time for the dependencies.  Luckily this does not conflict with .NET 4.5.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that in theory, you might not need it if you are building and running on a high enough .Net framework version, because the reason it was invented in the first place is to support using new .Net language features with older framework or compiler versions.

However
a) trying to see if you really can remove 'Microsoft.Bcl.Build' and its friends 'Microsoft.Bcl.Build' and 'Microsoft.Bcl.Async' from your solution everywhere is relatively hard work. By contrast, just adding the package reference everywhere the compiler tells you to is quite easy, and does little harm because it will always 'just work' even on newer framework versions, and

b) I'm not sure that the set of language features the packages support is actually fixed. It actually might be changing over time as new Bcl package versions come out, in which case the above theory can become invalidated.

Comment: Actually the package reference DOES cause a problem because it requires a package.config to exist which is no longer the case once you switch to PackageReference.